# Creating a array of counts from an indented string in python

Tags: python, string, algorithm

```
james
 gifts
   PS
    Gta.game
    crooks.movie
   xbox       
    fallout.game
karen
 brave.movie
 destiny.game
 flowers
```

a string str contains the paths above.
Im trying to get max of counts of the characters to a game
for example:

```
james->gifts->xbox->fallout.game=26
karen->destiny.game=17
```

I'm preparing for my internship interview next month and I'm unable to get around this one problem.I could solve most of the string medium-hard problems in Hackerrank using C. I usually code in C but I feel for strings manipulations like these python is better.

The approach I'm thinking is to maintain a count to each game and then at every point to "if" with max to maintain a maximum of the counts.
for example:
_

```
count to occurrence of next space  
james(count=5)  
gifts(count=10)  
xbox(count=14)  
fallout.game(count=26)
```

but this approach fails to ignore the counts of movie and if the same person has other games . The other approach I'm thinking is to traverse to the game first and then backtrack to the person counting, but even this has the same issue as before.

Any help on how to approach this problem will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right that Python is much better than C for strings.

In the algorithm, I would use a stack, implemented by a simple Python list.
I would traverse the file line by line, each time updating the stack. The number of spaces at the beginning of each line would tell me if I need to push the line to the stack, or to first pop 1 or more items from the stack, and only then push the line to the stack.

Then, whenever I get to a game, I can calculate the total number of characters in it by adding the number of characters in the words that are currently in the stack. I would use the function lstrip to remove spaces from the beginning of a line.

```
num_of_chars = sum([len(word.lstrip()) for word in stack])
```

In the example you gave, this is what the stack is going to be in every iteration:

```
[]
['james']
['james',' gifts']
['james',' gifts','   PS']
['james',' gifts','   PS','    Gta.game']
['james',' gifts','   PS','    crooks.movie']
['james',' gifts','   xbox']
['james',' gifts','   xbox','    fallout.game']
['karen']
['karen',' brave.movie']
['karen',' destiny.game']
['karen',' flowers']
```